# jQuery - actions with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My script:

jsfiddle.net/jcfcymsx/

What I want:

**Issue #1** - When is checkbox .parent checked, show array values of metdata1 or metdata2, if .child1 or .child2 is checked too. If are both .child checkboxes checked I want to show summed values of both arrays. There is an error - when is checked .parent and .child2 only, the displayed value is doubled. How to solve it?

**Issue #2** - I would like to have all 3 checkboxes checked on pageload and get a summed value of both arrays without need to click. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check [http://jsfiddle.net/jcfcymsx/1/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with this line:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
```

this runs the loop for each checkbox, so if all three are ticked, it will run 3 times.

If `child1` is ticked, this line:

```
metdata[i] = metdata1[i];
```

resets the value to `metdata1` so it doesn't matter how many times it runs.

If `child1` is not ticked (but `child2` is) then this line:

```
metdata[i] = metdata[i] + metdata2[i];
```

gets run twice (for parent and child2) and so you get double values.

To Fix:
Simply remove the loop: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcfcymsx/3/

---

To have the values set initially, add `checked='checked'` to each of the checkboxes and run `recalculate()` on load.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcfcymsx/4/

Answer (score 0):

issue 1 : In your recalculate function, I dont understood why do you have this row : `$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {`. The only thing to do is begining with an `metadata`array of zeros and add, if you need, the values of metadata1 and metadata2

issue 2 : just check the checkboxes on the `$(document).ready` function and call your recalculate function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var metdata1 = [34, 32, 32, 35, 36, 39];
    var metdata2 = [54, 57, 58, 63, 67, 69];    

    function recalculate() {                                             

    var metdata = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < metdata1.length; i++) {     
      metdata[i] = 0; 
    }

     $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {            

            if ($('input.child1').is(':checked')) {
              for(var i = 0; i < metdata1.length; i++) {
                metdata[i] = metdata1[i];
              }
            }
            if ($('input.child2').is(':checked')) {
              for(var i = 0; i < metdata2.length; i++) {
                metdata[i] = metdata[i] + metdata2[i];
              }
            }
    });

    if ($('input.parent').is(':checked')) {    
    $("#output").html(metdata +" ");
    }

    }


    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
    });

});
```

And the link : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcfcymsx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="parent" checked><b>Parent</b></p>   
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="child1" checked>Child 1
  <input type="checkbox" class="child2" checked>Child 2
</p>

<span id="output"></span>
```

**Using JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var metdata1 = [34, 32, 32, 35, 36, 39];
    var metdata2 = [54, 57, 58, 63, 67, 69];                                             
    function recalculate()
    {
        if ($('input.parent').is(':checked'))
        {
            var metdata = [];
            var ischild1checked = $('input.child1').is(':checked'), ischild2checked = $('input.child2').is(':checked');
            if (ischild1checked)
            {
                metdata=metdata1.slice();
            }
            if (ischild2checked)
            {
                metdata = metdata2.slice();
                for(var i = 0; i < metdata2.length && ischild1checked; i++)
                {
                    metdata[i] += metdata1[i];
                }
            }
            $("#output").html(metdata+"");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#output").html("");
        }
    }

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(event) {
            recalculate();
    });
    recalculate();
});
```

**Using PURE JS** (Added so anyone can refer)

```
var metdata1 = [34, 32, 32, 35, 36, 39];
var metdata2 = [54, 57, 58, 63, 67, 69];

function recalculate()
{
    var output_elem = document.getElementById("output");
    if (document.querySelector("input[class=parent]").checked)
    {
        var metdata = [];
        var ischild1checked = document.querySelector("input[class=child1]").checked, ischild2checked = document.querySelector("input[class=child2]").checked;
        if (ischild1checked)
        {
            metdata=metdata1.slice();
        }
        if (ischild2checked)
        {
            metdata = metdata2.slice();
            for(var i = 0; i < metdata2.length && ischild1checked; i++)
            {
                metdata[i] += metdata1[i];
            }
        }
        output_elem.innerHTML = metdata;
    }
    else
    {
        output_elem.innerHTML = "";
    }
}

function addEvents()
{
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
        for(var i=0,n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++)
        {
            checkboxes[i].addEventListener( 'change', function() {
                recalculate();
            });
        }
}

if(window.addEventListener)
{
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addEvents());
}
else if(document.body.attachEvent)
{
        document.body.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", addEvents());
}

recalculate();
```

Handled all cases with code simplified.
Note :

1. Avoid using many loops.
2. No need to initialize metdata with 0's.
3. Use(d) pure JS functions wherever needed instead of relying on third parties.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jcfcymsx/5/)

Comment: Sorry, I just want to suggest it. It doesn't mean that I don't like Jquery/other third parties. As just I focussed in the logic, I changed them to pure JS. Modified the answer now. Thanks for reporting it. Will do it clearly hereafter.